# GAE Datastore ID

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I've created two different Entities, one a User and one a Message they can create. I assign each user an ID and then want to assign this ID to each message which that user creates. How can I go about this? Do I have to do it in a query?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using Python NDB, you can having something like the following:

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    # put your fileds here

class Message(ndb.Model):
    owner = ndb.KeyProperty()
    # other fields
```

Create and save a User:

```
user = User(field1=value1, ....)
user.put()
```

Create and save a Message:

```
message = Message(owner=user.key, ...)
message.put()
```

Query a message based on user:

```
messages = Message.query().filter(Message.owner==user.key).fetch() # returns a list of messages that have this owner
```

For more information about NDB, take a look at [Python NDB API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/).

Also, you should take a look at [Python Datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/) in order to get a better understanding of data modeling in App Engine.

Comment: When creating an entity ancestor group as described, be sure you to handle the constraint of one write per second for the group. So if a user gets five messages at once, some exception handling will be needed.